# How to update a firebase server after making a change?

Tags: python, firebase, flask, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-run

I've set up a Flask server which is hosted on Firebase integrated with Cloud Run, I'm only making changes to html at the moment and using the command "firebase serve" with my localhost, however when I refresh the window and when I stop the server and restart it, my changes are still not showing up. I must be googling wrong because I can't find what I'm looking for: is there some sort of an update command, or do I need to re-build and re-deploy every time?

Comment: Firebase can't host a flask server.  What have you actually done?  Firebase Hosting can only serve static content.

Comment: @DougStevenson It turns out it can host dynamic content as well! I was intrigued so I wanted to try it out: https://medium.com/firebase-developers/hosting-flask-servers-on-firebase-from-scratch-c97cfb204579

Comment: You're actually using Cloud Run.  Firebase Hosting isn't actually handling the deployment or running any code. It's just proxying the incoming request and delivering the response.  This is important to note as part of your question.

Comment: @DougStevenson I see, sorry to leave that part out, I just assumed the question pertained to firebase commands like the "firebase serve", I'll edit it to include that thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Firebase emulator suite isn't proxying the request to Cloud Run in the way you expect, you should open an issue on the [firebase-tools GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools) and provide reproduction steps so they can diagnose.  You should make sure that your installation of firebase-tools is fully up to date.

Note that the CLI will *not* deploy any new code to Cloud Run. You still have to run gcloud to update the backend.

Comment: The changes I've been making are purely to the frontend at the moment, not changes to the actual server, typically should these small changes show up on refresh?

Comment: Yes, changes to local static content should show up immediately on browser refresh. You might want to look at the network monitor window in your browser to figure out what's actually going on.

Comment: Yeah I can't figure out what's happening, but when I do 'gcloud builds submit...' followed by 'gcloud beta run deploy --image...' and then 'firebase serve', my html is up to date, I don't want to go through that every time I make an update to static file tho :/